# Convert cdr (Corel Draw) using .net

Tags: c#, .net, coreldraw

Im having a hard time converting cdr files to jpgs for previews using c#.net. someone told me that cdr files have embedded bitmap, is there an easy way to extract it?

right now im running a realy bad solution of, from my application, calling uniconvertor to convert to svg, then converting the svg file to jpg using imagemagick. is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well I can't convert your `cdr` using .Net, but I think I can convert your `car`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i just used com interop to export the images, had to install coreldraw and reference the CorelDRAW 15.0 Type Library, still not the best solution but better then the one i was using

Answer (score 7):

You will need to copy the type library from corelDRAW: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Corel\CorelDRAW Graphics Suite 13\Programs\CorelDraw.tlb` into your `/bin` folder and create a reference to it. Once you have done this you should be able to export .CDR files to many different formats. The sample code below converts .cdr to .png.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using CorelDRAW;

    namespace WebApplication1
    {
        public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CorelDRAW.Application cdr =
                    new Application();

                cdr.OpenDocument(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\500074.cdr", 1);
                cdr.ActiveDocument.ExportBitmap(
                    @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\newImage.png",
                    CorelDRAW.cdrFilter.cdrPNG,
                    CorelDRAW.cdrExportRange.cdrCurrentPage,
                    CorelDRAW.cdrImageType.cdrRGBColorImage,
                    0, 0, 72, 72,
                    CorelDRAW.cdrAntiAliasingType.cdrNoAntiAliasing,
                    false,
                    true,
                    true,
                    false,
                    CorelDRAW.cdrCompressionType.cdrCompressionNone,
                    null).Finish();
                cdr.ActiveDocument.Close();
                cdr.Quit();
            }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

This code would convert the .cdr to .pdf:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CorelDRAW.Application cdr =
             new Application();

        cdr.OpenDocument(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\500074.cdr", 1);
        cdr.ActiveDocument.PublishToPDF(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewImage.pdf");
        cdr.ActiveDocument.Close();
        cdr.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: i was earlier using .Convert but that was throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

I know that CDR file format specification and SDK is avaliable through Corel Technology programm http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Content/1152796559574

Comment: i realy dont want to develop something from the ground up, i just need a thumbnail from the cdr file, the above solution works, but its far from a good solution